# Communicating between nio OP_READ and OP_WRITE operations

Tags: java, nio

I'm trying to implement java.nio Selector based http server (for fun). On `key.isReadable()` I'm reading data like this:

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
//Gathering whole client request
((ByteBufferQueue) key.attachment()).enqueue(buf);
key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
```

Please, look at gathering client's request. Is it a common practice to collect ByteBuffers in some kind of queues during OP_READ operations? Is there any other (more optimal) way to communicate between OP_READ and OP_WRITE operations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allocate a ByteBuffer per accepted channel, and save it as the key attachment, or in a session object that is used as the key attachment, that might contain other things as well.

When OP_READ fires, you should then *read.* Don't futz around queuing things.

NB OP_WRITE is almost always ready, except when the socket send buffer is full. It is therefore not correct to register it as an interestOp *except* when the socket buffer is full, which you can detect by write() returning zero. At all other times you should just write when you have something to write. If write() returns zero, *then* register OP_WRITE (and not OP_READ), and when you get it, retry the write: if it completes, deregister OP_WRITE and register OP_READ. If you have OP_WRITE registered all the time, the selector will never wait, it will just spin.

Comment: Sorry, may I hijack your answer to ask one more detail? Now I need to pass data between OP_READ and some Worker threads. Once again I made it through some Job objects (attached to client's key) and ConcurrentLinkedQueues for request and response ByteBuffers. I do interestOps(OP_WRITE), when responseQueue is not empty. Is that all a good idea? It looks good, when coding, but would it perform well?

Comment: No, you should use Op_WRTIE in the way I described.

Comment: But worker (that generates reply) is runing in separate thread. I can't just give buffer to it. I need to synchronize worker somehow. Pass buffer copy instead of queue?

Comment: @Oroboros You can just write directly to the channel from the worker thread. The worker thread does need to know where to put the response, which means he needs the channel and either the write buffer or the session object, whichever you're using.